Docker on Raspberry Pi keeps creating volumes even if explicitly mapped in docker compose
I'm using the following docker compose file to start a container on the Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu.
The docker version is 26.0.1, build d260a54.
RPI 4, Ubuntu 22.04 server (just CLI) with latest updates 64-bit.
version: "3.7"

services:
  mosquitto:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    hostname: mosquitto
    container_name: mosquitto
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mosquitto/config/:/etc/mosquitto
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mosquitto/data/:/var/lib/mosquitto/
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mosquitto/log/:/var/log/mosquitto/

Besides mapped volumes, this docker compose creates two empty volumes on the host machine in /var/lib/docker/volumes/ for unknown reasons. The image below presents the situation after two runs of docker compose up —d.

Any help eliminating this behaviour (creating empty volumes) would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Note that stopping and starting a container does not create new volume folders, but issuing docker compose up does cause 2 new volume folders every start.
Each folder contains an empty _data subfolder.
I've checked that each mapped volume is accessible and writable from the container level (creating some dummy, empty text files from the container's sh).

This can happen if the Dockerfile includes a VOLUME directive.  Can you [edit] the question to include the source code you've written?

As @DavidMaze said, in case Dockerfile is set up to use more volumes that you are binding to it will create anonymous docker volumes. If i quote from their docs: "Anonymous volumes are given a random name that's guaranteed to be unique within a given Docker host. Just like named volumes, anonymous volumes persist even if you remove the container that uses them, except if you use the --rm flag when creating the container, in which case the anonymous volume is destroyed.". This is most common when dealing with them.

Not sure if I get you right, but I do not use anything other than the docker-compose file as presented in the question. It pulls precompiled 'eclipse-mosquitto' image from the public Docker repository so there is no Dockerfile at all.
